# Failed to connect to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I get this console error every time I try to run this rs private server. Pretty much everything is connected to a mysql db.

I've been messing around with this for quite awhile but can't figure out whats wrong. If there is any specific files you may need to look at to help me figure out whats wrong, tell me and I'll post it.

All help would be highly appreciated!

```
[Stage - 1] Launching Elunity...
[Stage - 2] Loaded object configurations
[Stage - 3] Loaded region configurations
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1 432 637 479 787 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the   server was 0 milliseconds ago.
Failed to connect to MySQL database
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2214)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:773)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at paladious.model.players.Highscores.process(Highscores.java:17)
at paladious.Server.main(Server.java:117)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1 432 637 479 777 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2137)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:290)
... 14 more
[Stage - 4] Loaded single event manager
[Stage - 7] Loaded NPC drops
[Stage - 8] Loaded player punishments and starters
[Stage - 10] Elunity online on port :43594
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I assume it is a networking error, check your internet connection?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not my internet connection as it works just fine for everything else.

I'll try to do what Luke told me, then I'll come back with the results ^^

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrapped exception and not really interesting. It is the root cause of the exception which actually tells us something about the root cause. Please look a bit further in the stacktrace. The chance is big that you'll then face a SQLException: Connection refused or SQLException: Connection timed out.

If this is true in your case as well, then all the possible causes are:

1. IP address or hostname in JDBC URL is wrong.
2. Hostname in JDBC URL is not recognized by local DNS server.
3. Port number is missing or wrong in JDBC URL.
4. DB server is down.
5. DB server doesn't accept TCP/IP connections.
6. Something in between Java and DB is blocking connections, e.g. a firewall or proxy.

To solve the one or the either, follow the following advices:

1. Verify and test them with ping.
2. Refresh DNS or use IP address in JDBC URL instead.
3. Verify it based on my.cnf of MySQL DB.
4. Start it.
5. Verify if mysqld is started without the --skip-networking option.
6. Disable firewall and/or configure firewall/proxy to allow/forward
   the port.